# Jmeter upload file in asp webform (using devexpress)

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, devexpress, jmeter

I desperately looking for a way to create scenario to upload file from asp.net that using devexpress.

from this page: http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter

the example is using simple open dialog:

and the parameter name needed to be mentioned is the "name" of the input, which is "dataFile"

using devexpress I can't find the name of the input, because devexpress using javascript on the browse button and have no "name" parameter that should be provided.

Bellow is the jmeter scenario example.
http://blazemeter.com/sites/default/files/images/uldl1.png

How can I upload file using asp.net web-form that using devexpress component?

Thanks.

Comment: please make sure that your are passing the correct header data along with your HTTP request.

Comment: I'm sure that my header data are correct because when I record using HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder in simple php page, it work like charm. The only problem is when I record in asp.net page that using devexpress, it can't catch the even so the upload file scenario didn't recorded. Have any ideas why this is happened?

Comment: That possibly happens it there is an AJAX call or an internal call to servlet (JAVA). To overcome this you can use firebug in firefox and manually create http/https requests in Jmeter.

Comment: further you will have to do correlation wherever it is required.

Comment: yes, there is AJAX call in the button. If I have to do it manually because of that, that's mean that there are no ways to capture the upload event via recorder?

Comment: Yes Jmeter doesnot execute any Javascript code which are within the webpage. you may try using Badboy to capture your script and export the script to Jmeter.